# Angular 7 how to display formatted properties on template?

Tags: angular

I have this following model:

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public id: number,        
    public name?: string,       
    public adresses?: Address[]
) {}
```

And Address is a model like this:

```
export class Address{
constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: Type,
    public street?: string,
    public number?: string,
    public zipCode?: string,      
    public city?: string,
    public state?: string
) {}

export enum Type {
   MAIN = 'MAIN',
   MAIL = 'MAIL'
}
```

So a User can have many adresses. I want to display the one of those (where Type = MAIN) inside me template, So on my component Im doing this:

```
getMainAddressFormatted() {
    const mainAddress = this.user.adresses
        .filter(a => a.type === Type.MAIN)
        .pop();

   // Now I want to return format address like: "Street, Number, City-State"       
}
```

And on my template I'm doing:

```
<h6 class="address">{{ getMainAddressFormatted() }}</h6>
```

I'm not sure if is that a right way to do that, because on every state change Angular will call this method again and again.

Beside that, I want to be able to return formatted adresses on other components too (something like a overrided toString()), so I split this method: on my component I filter the list of adresses to get the main address, and call **mainAddress.getFormattedAddress()** on my model. But when I call it I get:

> address.getMainAddressFormatted is not a function

Whats the best way (the right way) to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do that by creating a custom pipe. I think it is the best way to do that thinking about of usability and reuse.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Address, Type} from 'app/shared/model/address.model';

@Pipe({name: 'mainAddressFormatted'})
export class MainAddressFormattedPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(adresses: Address[]): string {
        if (!adresses) {
            return '';
        }
        const main = adresses.filter(m => {
            return m.type === Type.MAIN;
        }).pop();

        return main.street + ', ' + main.number + ', ' + main.city + '-' + main.state;
    }
}
```

And on my template I'm doing:

```
<h6 class="address">{{ user.adresses | mainAddressFormatted }}</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your existing implementation, it should work except you are not returning any value from the `getMainAddressFormatted()` like:

```
getMainAddressFormatted() {
   var address = "your string value"
   return address;
}
```

I tried your code with some modification and worked for me.

Refer below sample example:

HTML:

```
<div class="example-container">
  <div>List of address</div>
  <div *ngFor="let obj of list">
  <h6 class="address">{{ getMainAddressFormatted(obj) }}</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {

  list: any[] = [{ "Street": "A", "Number": "1", "City": "Mumbai", "State": "Maharashtra" }, { "Street": "B", "Number": "2", "City": "New Mumbai", "State": "Maharashtra" }, { "Street": "C", "Number": "3", "City": "Satara", "State": "Maharashtra" }];


  getMainAddressFormatted(obj) {
    var address = obj.Street + " " + obj.Number + " " + obj.City + "-" + obj.State;
    return address;
  }
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wat2vx)